# Is it safe to manualy install RoundCube 1.0?

Tags: upgrade

I am running VestaCP on Ubuntu 14.04.  RoundCube was installed by VestaCP but it was done by the last release version 0.9.5.  Now I need a feature in 1.0 so I need to upgrade but there isn't a package for the new version.

Could I just rename the folder the package manager created and put the new version in there?  (Since this is only a website)

I am new to Linux so I am been careful not to break something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used it, so I can't vouch for it, but there's a [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) available: [RoundCube Backport PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tuxpoldo/+archive/ubuntu/roundcube?field.series_filter=trusty). This will let you use v1.0.3 while still using the package manager.

Comment: I am just running a backup then I will give it a try.  I didn't know about PPA's thanks :)